# best way to index from Oracle/relational DB into Elastic search

Tags: oracle, jdbc, elasticsearch, relational-database, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an Oracle Database with a large amount of data (300 million). I want to import some of them into Elastic search to follow them in "almost" real-time. The idea was to integrate the jprante river into ES cluster: I make an SQL request to select the right fields and import data on regular bases.

But rivers are deprecated. Here is my problem : Should I use the jrpante river as a feeder, which is possible (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-jdbc-river-is-going-to-expire-if-yes-then-what-is-the-alternative-to-connect-the-database/497) or try a connection through rabbitMQ ([what is the better way to index data from Oracle/relational tables into elastic search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486119/what-is-the-better-way-to-index-data-from-oracle-relational-tables-into-elastic)). What are the advantages of each solution ?

Any piece of advice is welcome :) Thx in advance !

Comment: Have you found the solution? What was that?